# Pass a NULL value to DateTime Field in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, datetime, default-constraint

My database table is like this

```
CREATE TABLE MYBUDGET.tbl_CurrentProperty
(
    [PropID]            INT             NOT NULL  IDENTITY(1,1),
    [UpdatedOn]         DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    [Amount]            MONEY           NOT NULL,
    [Remarks]           VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
)
ALTER TABLE MYBUDGET.tbl_CurrentProperty ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CurrentProperty_PropID PRIMARY KEY ([PropID])
ALTER TABLE MYBUDGET.tbl_CurrentProperty ADD CONSTRAINT DF_CurrentProperty_UpdatedOn DEFAULT (DATEADD(MINUTE,30,DATEADD(HOUR, 5, GETUTCDATE()))) FOR [UpdatedOn]
ALTER TABLE MYBUDGET.tbl_CurrentProperty ADD CONSTRAINT CK_CurrentProperty_Amount CHECK([Amount] > -1)
GO
```

I'm using LINQ to SQL. In C# I need to pass only [Amount] and [Remarks] fields and other fields must be used with their default values ([PropID] and [UpdatedOn]).

In C# I create tbl_CurrentProperties object like below,

```
tbl_CurrentProperties currentProperties = new tbl_CurrentProperties();
currentProperties.Amount = 50.00M;
currentProperties.Remarks = "remarks";
```

and then submit the object to the data context. But here, Linq assigned `'1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM'` for UpdatedOn field. But this violate the SQL datetime range `1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM` and Occurring an exception. Also I can't assign a NULL value manually for a `DateTime` field since its a not nullable type. Anyhow I need to make this to use its DEFAULT Constraint. How do I do this?

---

PS: I want to use it like this because, My database is Online and Users are in different locations. So If I used DateTime.Now, the time in the user machine may be wrong, and It insert a wrong value into DB. I need to use SQL server time always.

Comment: Of course, if you moved your business logic out of your database and into your code, then you wouldn't have this issue :-)

Comment: some things like date created are much better to have in the db

Comment: @Andrey: A lot of people would strongly disagree with you. Maybe this was acceptable 10 years ago, but now all business logic should arguably be centralised in code.

Comment: i don't think that's business, date added is data integrity.  If there is a business added date, i would store it separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Andrey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305416/andrey) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750193/pass-a-null-value-to-datetime-field-in-linq/4750307#4750307) is partly right.  I just tested this and here's what I found.

In your dbml designer, on your `UpdatedOn` column set the following:

```
Auto Generated Value = True 
Nullable = False
```

Then, on an `INSERT` if you use [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) to look at the generated SQL, you'll see that `UpdatedOn` is **not included in the INSERT**.  Not even a null value. This is important: for SQL Server to use a default value for that colum, the column *must be omitted* from the `INSERT`. If you set `Nullable = True` on the `UpdatedOn`, LINQ to SQL *might* be including the column on the `INSERT` with a null value.

FYI, immediately after the `INSERT` there should be a `SELECT` where LINQ to SQL is retrieving the auto-generated value, so your entity object has the latest value.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you open your `DBML` file using `XML Editor` and change that column's type from `DateTime` to `DateTime?` by allowing nulls. Save it and the code will be generated for you.

Whenever `LINQ to SQL` generates wrong `DBML`, it is better to edit it yourself.

Comment: the dbml generates the wrong xml because you set up the settings wrong. See my answer

Comment: Thanks for the response. but setting this value to NULL was not worked. As shaunmartin and Andrey mentioned turning "Auto Generated Value = true" is the correct thing. Anyway, thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 0):

Open your dbml and turn on 
"Auto Generated Value" = true for the fields that are auto generated.  You should be all good with passing nulls in

Comment: Thanks Andrey.It passing a NULL value. But since this field is NOT NULL, this error is occurring. "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UpdatedOn', table 'myDataContext.tbl_CurrentProperty'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: This looks like a design problem.  Your db should either be reviving a value to set the field, auto generating the value (in which case my solution would work), or allowing the field to be null.  You should not be using something like a min date time to represent a null.  If you for some reason do need the sql min date time in your code you can get it as System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue()

Comment: @Kushan: This answer is correct. As shaunmartin has noted, it will not work if combined with decyclone's answer. You need to set the column back to be not nullable and to `DateTime` (not `DateTime?`) and then set `Auto Generated = True` as Andrey suggested.